# Pro-rating of a sales target

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my work, in the sales team, each person holds a portfolio whose value changes throughout the quarter based on products that were implemented and products that churned. So the performance is measured at the end of the quarter by averaging out value of the portfolio for 90 days. Say you are managing an account - X (constant value), and at the end of the Q you have Y1 and Y2 products implemented. therefore your performance is X* [(Y1*30/90)+(Y2*49/90)]. 30 and 49 being number of days for which products Y1 and Y2 were implemented. Therefore longer the implementation time, more points towards performance. Quarterly targets are set on these averages. I would like to know if there is any formula that would calculate what the new target would be if the account owner takes leave for a long time and by the time he comes back some products have churned, reasons being out of his control. Say the previous Q average was 100, target for next Q was 10% so 110. Account owner takes leave on 30th day of the Q and when he gets back on the 60th day of the quarter the portfolio stands at 97 points (not average value but unique value of that day). How can target be adjusted keeping in mind the candidate only has 30 more days to achieve it.